# VS code keeps reconnecting to remote ssh

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

Problem: VS code keeps disconnecting / reconnecting ssh with remote machine.
After entering password it immediately comes back with password prompt again.
The logs suggest that vs code server fails.
Are there any vs code server logs I can review on the remote machine?

Details: VS code ver 1.4.5 / Windows 10;

Remote: Macbook Air (High Sierra)

Logs are below:

```
   [09:49:41.088] > Password:
   [09:49:41.088] Showing password prompt
   [09:49:45.455] Got password response
   [09:49:45.456] "install" wrote data to terminal: "********"
   [09:49:45.889] > 028771948a23: running
   [09:49:45.922] > Acquiring lock on /Users/user/.vscode-server/bin/5763d909d5f12fe19f215cbfdd
    > 29a91c0fa9208a/vscode-remote-lock.user.5763d909d5f12fe19f215cbfdd29a91c0fa9
   > 208a
   > \ln /Users/user/.vscode-server/bin/5763d909d5f12fe19f215cbfdd29a91c0fa9208a
   > /vscode-remote-lock.user.5763d909d5f12fe19f215cbfdd29a91c0fa9208a.target /U
   > sers/user/.vscode-server/bin/5763d909d5f12fe19f215cbfdd29a91c0fa9208a/vscod
   > e-remote-lock.user.5763d909d5f12fe19f215cbfdd29a91c0fa9208a
   > 
   [09:49:45.943] > Found existing installation at /Users/user/.vscode-server/bin/5763d909d5f12
   > fe19f215cbfdd29a91c0fa9208a...
   > 
   [09:49:46.017] > Found running server...

   [09:49:46.050] > Checking server status on port 58236 with curl
   > 
   [09:49:46.083] > 000
    > 028771948a23##28##
   > 
   [09:49:46.083] Received install output: 028771948a23##28##
   [09:49:46.083] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
   [09:49:46.364] "install" terminal command done
   [09:49:46.364] Install terminal quit with output: 
   [09:49:47.091] Running script with connection command: "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe" -T -D 
   55978 10.0.0.134 bash
   [09:49:47.092] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
   [09:49:47.275] > 
   [09:49:47.281] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
   [09:49:50.747] > Password:
   [09:49:50.748] Showing password prompt
```